# accessing mongoid fields of a document through belongs_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

So here is an example of what I'm asking.
I have a post model and a writer model.

```
class Post
  include Mongoid::Document
  ...
  belongs_to :writer, class_name: 'Writer', inverse_of: :posts
end

class Writer
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name,   :type => String
  has_many :posts, inverse_of: :writer
end
```

From other design considerations, posts are not embedded in the writer model.

Now I want to have the Writers name displayed in the post view.
something like:

```
<div>
  Writer: <%= @post.writer.name %>
</div>
```

default scaffold controller for now.

First thing I noticed - is that in the mongo the field is writer_id.

So what is the correct way to deduce the name from an id (another query? really?)

The error I'm getting:
`` undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass ``

When I try it in rails console:

`ccc=Post.find_by(name:"bla bla")

ccc.writer >>> nil

ccc.writer_id >>> "5284c0bc1d41c837c1000001"`

Comment: That should work just fine, as Mongoid generates the ActiveModel association helper methods that you want.  Did it not work for you?  You don't state your results.

Comment: I'm getting:  
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

I figured that becuase I don't have writer and have only writer_id

Comment: When I try it in rails console:  
ccc=Post.find_by(name:"bla bla")  
ccc.writer >>> nil  
ccc.writer_di >>> "5284c0bc1d41c837c1000001"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well - indeed it should work. I was barking on the wrong tree. In case anyone thinks like me that this is their problem - look at what really happened here:
[multiple belongs_to in mongoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20248655/multiple-belongs-to-in-mongoid)