# multiple belongs_to in mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

The models:

```
class Post
  include Mongoid::Document
  ...
  belongs_to :writer, class_name: 'Writer', inverse_of: :posts
  belongs_to :reviewer, class_name: 'User', inverse_of: :reviewed_posts
end

class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name,   :type => String
  ...
  has_many :reviewed_posts, class_name: 'Post', inverse_of: reviewer
end

class Writer < User
  has_many :posts, class_name: 'Post', inverse_of: :writer
end
```

Now I want to have the Writers name displayed in the post view.
something like:

```
<div>
  Writer: <%= @post.writer.name %>
</div>
```

default scaffold controller for now.

The error I'm getting:
`` undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass ``

When I try it in rails console:

`ccc=Post.find_by(name:"bla bla")

ccc.writer >>> nil

ccc.writer_id >>> "5284c0bc1d41c837c1000001"`

The reviewer on the other hand is A OK:

`ccc.reviewer - returns a perfect object`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is it a typo? "inverse_of: reviewer"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boaz,

When you say

```
ccc.writer_id >>> "5284c0bc1d41c837c1000001"
ccc.writer >>> nil
```

I suspect you create a `Post` while referencing a `User` instead of a `Writer`

`Mongoid` adds a `_type` field to your document when you use inheritance and every query has a "hidden" `_type` selector.

So when you do
`ccc.writer` Mongoid adds a `_type == Writer` to the query so you get `nil` because the ID you have is actually a `_type=User`

Comment: YES! That was it! in the form that creates the post I had a collection_select with User and not Writer
Thanks!